# PHP EXIF data not displaying

Tags: php, image, metadata, exif

I have been trying to display some basic EXIF data from a photo with no luck. My code is below. I just need to display a few basic pieces of information. I have EXIF enabled on the server and I know this image has EXIF data in there - but no data shows up with this set up. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
$exif_data = exif_read_data("http://www.findexif.com/client/samples/swiss_house.jpg");

        $emake = $exif_data['Make'];
        $emodel = $exif_data['Model'];
        $eexposuretime = $exif_data['ExposureTime'];
        $efnumber = $exif_data['FNumber'];
        $eiso = $exif_data['ISOSpeedRatings'];
        $edate = $exif_data['DateTime'];

    echo "Make: ". $emake . "<br>";
        echo "Model: ". $emodel . "<br>";
        echo "Exp: ". $eexposuretime . "<br>";
        echo "Date: ". $edate . "<br>";
        echo "ISO: ". $eiso . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filename of `exif_read_data` cannot be an URL.

If you still want to read EXIF data of external image, you need to download it first:

```
<?php
$imageURL = 'http://www.findexif.com/client/samples/swiss_house.jpg';
$localURL = '/tmp/swiss_house.jpeg';

// Use 'copy' function if you have PHP5
//  and the HTTP stream wrapper enabled on your server.
copy($imageURL, $localURL);

/**
 * This way if you don't have PHP5
$fp = fopen($localURL, 'w');
fwrite($fp, file_get_contents($imageURL));
fclose($fp);
 */

$exif_data = exif_read_data($localURL);

$emake = $exif_data['Make'];
$emodel = $exif_data['Model'];
$eexposuretime = $exif_data['ExposureTime'];
$efnumber = $exif_data['FNumber'];
$eiso = $exif_data['ISOSpeedRatings'];
$edate = $exif_data['DateTime'];

echo 'Make: '. $emake . '<br>';
echo 'Model: '. $emodel . '<br>';
echo 'Exp: '. $eexposuretime . '<br>';
echo 'Date: '. $edate . '<br>';
echo 'ISO: '. $eiso . '<br>';
```

Comment: I tried $imagePath = "http://www.findexif.com/client/samples/swiss_house.jpg";
$exif_data = exif_read_data($imagePath); with no luck, too. Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: @xtiaan In other word, you can't read EXIF data of external server, so you need to download it first.